# Update nested array object (put request)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an array inside a document of a collection called pown.

```
{
    _id: 123..,
    name: pupies,
    pups:[ {name: pup1, location: somewhere}, {name: pup2, ...}]
}
```

Now a user using my rest-service sends the entire first entry as put request:

```
{name: pup1, location: inTown}
```

After that I want to update this element in my database.

Therefore I tried this:

```
var updatedPup = req.body;
var searchQuery = { 
    _id : 123...,
    pups : { name : req.body.name }
}
var updateQuery = {
    $set: {'pups': updatedPup }
}
db.pown.update(searchQuery, updateQuery, function(err, data){ ... }
```

Unfortunately it is not updating anythig.
Does anyone know how to update an entire array-element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Neil pointed, you need to be acquainted with the [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)(used to select the fields) and the [positional operator $](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) (used to select a particular element in an array i.e the element matched in the original search query). If you want to replace the whole element in the array

```
var updateQuery= {
      "$set":{"pups.$": updatedPup}
    }
```

If you only need to change the location,

```
var updateQuery= {
  "$set":{"pups.$.location": updatedPup.location}
}
```

Comment: Close but no cigar. You're replacing too much and not explaining how this really works.

Comment: pups.$ was what I was after. tyvm

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that the selection in your query actually wants to update an embedded array element in your document. The first thing is that you want to use ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) instead, and then you also want the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) modifier to select the correct element:

```js
db.pown.update(
    { "pups.name": req.body.name },
    { "$set": { "pups.$.locatation": req.body.location } 
)
```

That would be the nice way to do things. Mostly because you really only want to modify the "location" property of the sub-document. So that is how you express that.

Comment: That's right, as ma08 pointed out it is possible to update the entire item. That's what I was after. tyvm :)

Comment: @NeilLunn Do you mean I shouldn't replace the entire object? I better should change field by field of the attribut? So "pups.$" isn't valid without a destination?